# JBoos exception for EJB deployment: cannot be cast to org.jboss.lang.Annotation

Tags: java, jboss, ejb

I am trying to deploy an old EJB application to verify one error, for that, I have used the jboss-4.0.5.GA server and deployed my ear file under server\default\deploy folder and started the server. but I get `java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy76 cannot be cast to org.jboss.lang.Annotation` exception.
This ear is working fine on the server, I have the same JBOSS version still getting this issue on my local.
Please check the following log snipped from server.log file:

```
2020-09-15 09:02:18,234 INFO  [org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.remote.WrapperDataSourceService] Bound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=DBPictureCard' to JNDI name 'java:DBPictureCard'
2020-09-15 09:02:18,305 INFO  [org.jboss.deployment.EARDeployer] Init J2EE application: file:/C:/test/jboss-4.0.5.GA/jboss-4.0.5.GA/server/default/deploy/PictureCardApp.ear
2020-09-15 09:02:18,808 WARN  [org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer] Found non-jar deployer for PictureCardBusinessEJB.jar: 
MBeanProxyExt[jboss.ejb:service=EJBDeployer]
2020-09-15 09:02:20,200 INFO  [org.jboss.deployment.EARDeployer] Init J2EE application: file:/C:/test/jboss-4.0.5.GA/jboss-4.0.5.GA/server/default/tmp/deploy/tmp8388441575443165668PictureCardApp.ear-contents/PictureCardDataEJB.ear
2020-09-15 09:02:20,739 INFO  [org.jboss.ejb.EjbModule] Deploying UserFacadeBean
2020-09-15 09:02:20,780 INFO  [org.jboss.ejb.EjbModule] Deploying UserBean
2020-09-15 09:02:20,818 INFO  [org.jboss.ejb.EjbModule] Deploying CustomerFacadeBean
2020-09-15 09:02:20,820 INFO  [org.jboss.ejb.EjbModule] Deploying CustomerBean
2020-09-15 09:02:20,822 INFO  [org.jboss.ejb.EjbModule] Deploying RoleFacadeBean
2020-09-15 09:02:20,824 INFO  [org.jboss.ejb.EjbModule] Deploying RoleBean
2020-09-15 09:02:21,732 ERROR [org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer] Could not create deployment: file:/C:/test/jboss-4.0.5.GA/jboss-4.0.5.GA/server/default/tmp/deploy/tmp8388441575443165668PictureCardApp.ear-contents/PictureCardDataWS.war
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy76 cannot be cast to org.jboss.lang.Annotation
    at org.jboss.lang.AnnotationHelper.getAnnotation(AnnotationHelper.java:80)
    at org.jboss.lang.AnnotationHelper.isAnnotationPresent(AnnotationHelper.java:61)
    at org.jboss.ws.integration.jboss.DeployerInterceptorJSE.isWebserviceDeployment(DeployerInterceptorJSE.java:125)
    at org.jboss.ws.integration.jboss.DeployerInterceptor.create(DeployerInterceptor.java:76)
    at org.jboss.ws.integration.jboss.DeployerInterceptorJSE.create(DeployerInterceptorJSE.java:74)
    at org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployerInterceptorSupport$XMBeanInterceptor.create(SubDeployerInterceptorSupport.java:180)
    at org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployerInterceptor.invoke(SubDeployerInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy35.create(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.create(MainDeployer.java:969)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.create(MainDeployer.java:959)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:818)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor53.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy8.deploy(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.deploy(URLDeploymentScanner.java:421)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.scan(URLDeploymentScanner.java:634)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.doScan(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:263)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner.startService(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:336)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy4.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.start(SARDeployer.java:302)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:766)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.deploy(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:482)
    at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:362)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:200)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:490)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2020-09-15 09:02:21,736 ERROR [org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner] Incomplete Deployment listing:

--- Incompletely deployed packages ---
org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentInfo@7d5bdba5 { url=file:/C:/test/jboss-4.0.5.GA/jboss-4.0.5.GA/server/default/deploy/PictureCardApp.ear }
  deployer: org.jboss.deployment.EARDeployer@b86944
  status: Deployment FAILED reason: Could not create deployment: file:/C:/test/jboss-4.0.5.GA/jboss-4.0.5.GA/server/default/tmp/deploy/tmp8388441575443165668PictureCardApp.ear-contents/PictureCardDataWS.war; - nested throwable: (java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy76 cannot be cast to org.jboss.lang.Annotation)
  state: FAILED
  watch: file:/C:/test/jboss-4.0.5.GA/jboss-4.0.5.GA/server/default/deploy/PictureCardApp.ear
  altDD: null
  lastDeployed: 1600140740261
  lastModified: 1600140738304
  mbeans:
```

Answer (score 0):

We just recently ran into the same exception when we tried to switch the JVM running the JBoss 4.0.5.GA server from Java 5 to Java 8.  I did manage to deploy my ear with an ejb under Java 8 by switching to JBoss 4.2.3.GA, but I had to add the following VM options to make it work:

-Djavax.management.builder.initial=org.jboss.system.server.jmx.MBeanServerBuilderImpl

-Djboss.platform.mbeanserver

-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote

I wasn't able to find a solution to make it work with JBoss 4.0.5.GA under Java 8.